# Sublime text replace multiple accented characters with unaccented ones at once

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I need to replace all characters with an accent in a text file, that is:

```
á é í ó ú ñ
```

for their non-accent equivalents:

```
a e i o u n
```

Can this be achieved via some regex command for the entire file at once?

---

**Update (Feb 1st, 2017)**

I took the [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38909594/1391441) by [Keith Hall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4473405/keith-hall) and turned into a Sublime package. You can find it here: [Remove​Non​Ascii​Chars](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/RemoveNonAsciiChars).

Comment: Not sure about the regex, but, personally, I would ensure Unicode support for whatever the file is for, instead.

Comment: That's not up to me sadly. There's no unicode support, thus why I need to replace the characters with accents.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use a regex like:

```
(?=\p{L})[^a-zA-Z]
```

to find the characters with diacritics.

- `(?=\p{L})` positive lookahead to ensure the next character is a Unicode letter
- `[^a-zA-Z]` negative character class to exclude letters without diacritics.

This is necessary because Sublime Text (or, more specifically, the [Boost regex engine](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/unicode.html) it uses for Find and Replace) doesn't support `\p{M}`. See http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html for more information on what the `\p` meta character does.

---

For replacing, unfortunately you will need to specify the characters to replace manually. To make it harder, ST doesn't seem to support the [POSIX character equivalents](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html#eq), nor does it support [conditionals in the replacement](https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/1524), which would allow you to do the find and replace in one pass, using capture groups.

Therefore, you would need to use multiple find expressions like:

```
[ÀÁÂÃÄÅ]
```

replace with

```
A
```

and

```
[àáâãäå]
```

replace with

```
a
```

etc.

which is a lot of manual work.

---

A much easier/quicker/less-manual-work approach would be to use the Python API instead of regex:

1. Tools menu -> Developer -> New Plugin
2. Paste in the following:

   ```
   import sublime
   import sublime_plugin
   import unicodedata

   class RemoveNonAsciiCharsCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
       def run(self, edit):
           entire_view = sublime.Region(0, self.view.size())
           ascii_only = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', self.view.substr(entire_view)).encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('utf-8')
           self.view.replace(edit, entire_view, ascii_only)
   ```
3. Save it in the folder ST recommends (which will be your `Packages/User` folder), as something like `remove_non_ascii_chars.py` (file extension is important, base name isn't)
4. View menu -> Show Console
5. Type/paste in `view.run_command('remove_non_ascii_chars')` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
6. The diacritics will have been removed (the characters with an accent will have been converted to their non-accented equivalents).

Note: the above will actually also remove all non-ascii characters as well...

Further reading:

- http://fabzter.com/blog/remove-nonspacing-characters-text-python
- [What is the best way to remove accents in a Python unicode string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517923/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-accents-in-a-python-unicode-string)

Comment: note, it is possible to [use snippets to prevent the need of using multiple Find and Replace operations](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/unicode-replacement-challenge/71794/3?u=kingkeith), but it wouldn't save the manual work of specifying which character to replace with.